# Optional query string enum parameter - openapi, springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, swagger, openapi

I have an OpenApi spec:

```
paths:
  /lessons:
    get:
      tags:
        - lesson
      operationId: getLessons
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: daysOfWeek
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/DaysOfWeekEnum'
```

Using swagger codegen this generates an endpoint like:

```
 @ApiOperation(value = "Get a collection lessons", nickname = "getLessons", notes = "", response = LessonDto.class, responseContainer = "List", tags={ "lesson", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "List of Lessons", response = LessonDto.class, responseContainer = "List") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/lessons",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<List<LessonDto>> _getLessons(@ApiParam(removed for brevity) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "daysOfWeek", required = false, defaultValue="new ArrayList<>()") List<DaysOfWeekEnum> daysOfWeek) {
        return getLessons(daysOfWeek);
    }
```

I use **TestRestTemplate** in a test like so:

```
ResponseEntity<List<LessonDto>> lessonDtos =
        testRestTemplate.exchange("/lessons", HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<LessonDto>>() {
            });
```

This url works:

```
/lessons?daysOfWeek=THURSDAY
```

These urls do not:

```
/lessons
/lessons?daysOfWeek=SOME_INVALID_VALUE
```

...and I get the following error:

> nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT
>   token

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was related to an [openapi-generator bug](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/1551). Summary being:

> When parameters of type array are added to an operation, the generated
>   Spring code includes an invalid defaultValue in the Spring MVC
>   parameter annotations

The fix was to upgrade to a later version of `openapi-generator` - `4.0.0` did the trick for me.

As an aside, the error message:

> exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
>   deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

..was a bit of a red herring and it was actually `TestRestTemplate` related i.e. the `ParameterizedTypeReference` part. Changing this to `String.class` identified the true nature of the error.

Answer (score 2):

In order to give you an `empty list`, you need to set the default value to be as an empty string:

```
@RequestParam(value = "daysOfWeek", 
              required = false, 
              defaultValue = "") List<DaysOfWeekEnum> daysOfWeek)
```